# Could not load file or assembly 'BusinessObjects.Enterprise.Sdk.ZipLib.netmodule'

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I am trying to follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227542(v=vs.80).aspx) guide to connect to a server running SAP Crystal Reports Enterprise 4.1 from my dev pc. When I run my solution, I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'BusinessObjects.Enterprise.Sdk.ZipLib.netmodule' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Some [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494766/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crystaldecisions-reportappserver-clientdoc) suggest that it is an issue between 32/64bit versions of the SDK, but I have tried both individually and experienced the same issue.

I also tried [this](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2057495) solution and I can see all those files are in my bin folder. Please also note that when I included the DLLs (CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework and CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore), I had to set these to "Embed Interop types": False and "Copy Local": True.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this Alex in the end, I am having the same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid not, in the end the decision was made to build the solution based on URL reporting, which was capable of achieving everything required and was well documented.

Answer (score 2):

Check Copy Local in the References to false

[image]